# Percona DB not starting: initscript mysql, action "start" failed

Tags: ubuntu, percona

After I installed Percona server I got this message:

```
 * Percona Server is distributed with several useful UDF (User Defined Function) from Percona Toolkit.
 * Run the following commands to create these functions:

    mysql -e "CREATE FUNCTION fnv1a_64 RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'libfnv1a_udf.so'"
    mysql -e "CREATE FUNCTION fnv_64 RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'libfnv_udf.so'"
    mysql -e "CREATE FUNCTION murmur_hash RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'libmurmur_udf.so'"

 * See http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/management/udf_percona_toolkit.html for more details

Job for mysql.service failed. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package percona-server-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of percona-server-server:
 percona-server-server depends on percona-server-server-5.6; however:
  Package percona-server-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package percona-server-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 percona-server-server-5.6
 percona-server-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@public-server-01:~/src# systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql (Percona Server) daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-09-30 04:26:52 UTC; 38min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 20916 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 30 04:26:41 public-server-01 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql (Percona Server) daemon...
Sep 30 04:26:41 public-server-01 mysql[20916]: * Starting MySQL (Percona Server) database server mysqld
Sep 30 04:26:52 public-server-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 30 04:26:52 public-server-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql (Percona Server) daemon.
Sep 30 04:26:52 public-server-01 systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
Sep 30 04:26:52 public-server-01 mysql[20916]: ...fail!
Sep 30 04:26:52 public-server-01 systemd[1]: mysql.service failed.
```

I don't understand why it is not starting.

I am running Ubuntu 15. 1GB of RAM...

Answer (score 1):

The error message "Package percona-server-server-5.6 is not configured yet." means that the packages are not installed. The Percona packages need to be installed in the correct order:
starting with the common libraries first, then client, then server-server.

When you use dpkg to install, you will see any errors reported by dpkg which have to be resolved first. Sometimes, simply running apt-get -f install will fix the problem by installing the required packages.

For Ubuntu 14.04:

```
dpkg-i percona-server-common-5.6_5.6.26-74.0-1.trusty_amd64.deb percona-server-client_5.6.26-74.0-1.trusty_amd64.deb percona-server-server-5.6_5.6.26-74.0-1.trusty_amd64.deb
```

Once you have no errors from dpkg, you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried with just apt-get install -f and it did not work either... I will try the next thing later.

Answer (score 0):

To force package install without starting the MySQL service, run:

```
RUNLEVEL=1 apt install -y percona-xtradb-cluster-57
```

<sup>Source: [Install packages without starting background processes and services](https://askubuntu.com/a/75560/78223).</sup>

It will stop daemons from starting after installing the package.

It's not clear why your *Percona Server* fails to start MySQL server, to check for details, run:

```
journalctl -xe
```

or check the MySQL logs:

```
tail -n50 /var/log/mysqld.log
```

The most common issue is to install/start *Percona Server* with cluster configuration which is not there yet, so the service fails to connect to the existing cluster.

If so, check your configuration files in `/etc/mysql/percona-xtradb-cluster.conf.d/`, especially `wsrep_cluster_address` in `wsrep.cnf`. Try uncommenting it first, before starting the service for the first time.

See also: [Installing Percona/MySQL unattended on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9743828/55075).

For documentation pages, check: [Percona XtraDB Cluster 5.7 Documentation](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/LATEST/index.html).